# Validating numeric field with 2 decimal places

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
           var textvalue = $("#txtNumeric").val();
           validateDecimal(textvalue);
           return true;
       });

   });

   function validateDecimal(value) {
       var RE = new RegExp(/^\d*\.\d\d$/);
       if (RE.test(value)) {
            return true;
       } else {
           alert("formate numeric with 2 decimal places!");
           return false;
       }
   }
```

I am using this script to validate my textnumeric field value with 2 decimal places.
its working properly at the time of validation.But if the textnumeric field value is correct I am not getting any value from that textfield to my ASP.NET code behind page(default.aspx.cs). 
Can anyone help me to resolve this ?

Comment: why don't to use asp.net validator controls?

Comment: I am asked to do it by jquery only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting validation logic into `onclick` handler. I suggest you to put into `submit` event handler instead.

```
$("form").submit(function () {
       var textvalue = $("#txtNumeric").val();
       return validateDecimal(textvalue);
}
```

The data should post into server side script properly.

Comment: yes its working but one problem is there .. I am using master page with many pages... so i can put formid from master page,

Comment: but when i am entering 12.0 or some value with one decimal its prompting for invalid value.,, and then that invalid data is getting saved in database.

Comment: This is the standard way to prevent form submitting but not all browsers follow the standard. So you may put a code
  event.preventDefault();
and pass event to function parameter...